# adding conditions inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
const AccountDetails = ({ accountDetails }) => {
    const tooltipContent = (
        <ul className="account-details-content">
            {accountDetails.filter((detail) => detail && Object.keys(detail).length).map((detail) => (
                <li key={detail.title}>
                    <span>{`${detail.title}:`}</span>
                    <span>{detail.formattedValue}</span>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );

    return (
        <Tooltip
            content={tooltipContent}
            placement="bottom"
            portalClassName="account-details-portal"
            tooltipType="popover"
            trigger="click"
        >
            <li>
                <i className="material-icons">description</i>
                <span>Details</span>
            </li>
        </Tooltip>
}
```

[What the code does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Agaz.png)

**I need to figure out how to remove "propertyManagementSoftwareOther" if the formatedValue is 'NA'. Basically don't show it at all.**

detail.title is the right side on the image.
detail.formattedValue is the left side in the image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow skphi13! It's difficult to figure out what you are asking from the code currently in your question. Do you think you could include all relevant code, format it, and elaborate your question?

Comment: Can you explain your ways instead just show your code? We can't reach your code but any way, you can use `filter` for array in Js can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a conditional in your map because it is displaying each line item separately. What you need to do is remove the `detail` that you don't want to display from the array. An easy solution would be to add another `filter` before your `map`:

```
const AccountDetails = ({ accountDetails }) => {
  const tooltipContent = (
    <ul className="account-details-content">
      {accountDetails
        .filter( detail => detail && Object.keys(detail).length)
        .filter( detail => detail.title === 'propertyManagementSoftwareOther' ? detail.value !== 'NA' : true )
        .map((detail) => (
          <li key={detail.title}>
            <span>{`${detail.title}:`}</span>
            <span>{detail.formattedValue}</span>
          </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <Tooltip
      content={tooltipContent}
      placement="bottom"
      portalClassName="account-details-portal"
      tooltipType="popover"
      trigger="click"
    >
      <li>
        <i className="material-icons">description</i>
        <span>Details</span>
      </li>
    </Tooltip>
}
```